# Check if option is selected appear an other option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like :

```
<select id="BanReason">
<option value="hack">Hack</option>
<option value="badlang">Bad Language</option>
<option value="scrammer">Scrammer</option>
</select>

<select id="BanLength">
<option value="1day">1 Day</option>
<option value="2days">3 Days</option>
<option value="1week">1 Week</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to do, if Scrammer is selected in #BadReason select 1 week in #BanLength automaticly.

Answer (score 0):

try using `change event` `BanReason` and based on this value pass the desired value to `BanLength` and trigger the change.:

```js
     $("#BanReason").on("change",function(){
               if(this.value == "scrammer"){
                $("#BanLength").val("1week").trigger("change");
               }
       });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="BanReason">
<option value="hack">Hack</option>
<option value="badlang">Bad Language</option>
<option value="scrammer">Scrammer</option>
</select>

<select id="BanLength">
<option value="1day">1 Day</option>
<option value="2days">3 Days</option>
<option value="1week">1 Week</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

On change event will help you to do this

```
$("#BanReason").on("change",function(){
    if($(this).val() == "scrammer")
        $("#BanLength").val("1week");
});
```

Added  a Fiddle to this 
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srivaish/vq2ro7sk/)